# Need help with the Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Well I am new to *Mathematica* and got really stuck solving this problem.

In class, I was ask to use the Lagrange multiplier method to find the maximum and minimum value  of $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ which lies on the curve $x^4 + 4xy + 2y^4 = 8$

What I did was

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2   
G[x_, y_] := x^4 + 4 x y + 2 y^4 - 8
gradf = {D[F[x, y], x], D[F[x, y], y]};
gradg = {D[G[x, y], x], D[G[x, y], y]};
Print["grad f = ", gradf]
output = grad f = {2 x,2 y}
Print["grad g = ", gradg]
output = grad g = {4 x^3+4 y,4 x+8 y^3}
Solve[{gradf[x, y] == lambda gradg[x, y], g[x, y] == 8}, {x, y, lambda}]
```

Then after this part I keep getting an error message or some ridiculous infinite number.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Similar: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78400, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63351, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36847

Comment: @belisaurius's solution below is a good one, but just to make explicit the errors in your above code:  (1) `gradf` and `gradf[x, y]` are not the same thing as far as Mathematica is concerned (you use these inconsistently);  (2) `G[x, y]` and `g[x, y]` are not interchangeable (you define the former and then use the latter in `Solve`);  (3) it's generally best practice to avoid defining capitalized variables, as they can't conflict with Mathematica's own predefined functions;  (4)  your `output` statements don't actually do anything.

Answer (score 16):

The "canonical" way in *Mathematica* is

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
g[x_, y_] := x^4 + 4 x y + 2 y^4 - 8
Maximize[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

If you want to make explicit usage of the Lagrange multiplier:

```
ss = N@Solve[Grad[f[x, y] + λ g[x, y], {x, y}] == 0 && g[x, y] == 0, {x, y, λ}, Reals]
```

gives the `{x, y}` coordinates of the maxs and mins.

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[f[x, y],      {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "Pastel",
             Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y} /. ss]}],
 ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Green}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

If you want to keep your own grad definitions you could write:

```
Solve[{gradf == λ gradg, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y, λ}, Reals] // N
```

Comment: bel, why not just use the third argument of `Solve[]` to throw out the complex solutions?

Comment: @J.M. Didn't work when I tried it first. Tried again after reading your comment and the obvious conclusion is that I made a mistake the first time. :)

Comment: nice and elegant; did not know about the third argument of `Solve`.

Comment: …and if you're still stuck in a version without `Grad[]`: `D[f, {{x, y}}]`.